# Logstash container is getting stoped automatically

Tags: docker, containers, logstash

I'm trying to start the docker container. I am using docker-elk.yml file to generate ELK containers.Elasticsearch and Kibana Containers are working fine.But for Logstash,it is starting and going into container bash but after sometimes it stops automatically.

Logs of container:

> [2019-04-11T08:48:26,882][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.6.0"}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:33,497][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,062][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,310][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,409][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,415][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,469][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
>
> New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,486][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,503][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
>
> Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,960][INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ] Beats inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5000"}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:34,985][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#"}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:35,077][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:35,144][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server] Starting server on port: 5000
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:35,499][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
>
> [2019-04-11T08:48:50,591][INFO ][logstash.outputs.file    ] Opening file {:path=>"/usr/share/logstash/output.log"}
>
> [2019-04-11T13:16:51,947][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] SIGTERM received. Shutting down.
>
> [2019-04-11T13:16:56,498][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline has terminated {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#"}
>
> Does it try to require a relative path? That's been removed in Ruby 1.9.
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require':
>
> It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
>   To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
>
> [ERROR] 2019-04-11 14:18:02.058 [main] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error:
>
> (GemspecError) There was a LoadError while loading logstash-core.gemspec: 
>   load error: psych -- java.lang.RuntimeException: BUG: we can not copy embedded jar to temp directoryoes it try to require a relative path? That's been removed in Ruby 1.9.
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require':
>
> It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
>   To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
>
> [ERROR] 2019-04-11 13:42:01.450 [main]
>
> Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (GemspecError) There was a LoadError while loading logstash-core.gemspec: load error: psych -- java.lang.RuntimeException: BUG: we can not copy embedded jar to temp directory

I have tried to remove tmp folder in container.But it is not working.

Comment: Seems like you don't have permissions: `we can not copy embedded jar to temp directoryoes`

Comment: I think I have done wrong configuration in logstash.conf.  When I replaced my current logstash.conf file with original logstash.conf without any filter and restarted docker-compose , it is working fine now.

Comment: want to know.Pathconfig  is in logstash.yml & also in pipeline.yml.then which one is taking  by docker first. Because as per docker-compose.yml,we have only mounted logstash.yml & given  pathconfig in that.For more reference just look out  compose yml file:https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml So I have checked through container bash that  pipeline.yml also contains this path config  with updated path.But we are only updating logstash.yml file because I have mounted only that with compose yml.So May be thats why it is saying pipeline.yml is ignored